# How can I replace numbers in the results of my query with text, before displaying in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
```

Result is:

```
ID    USERNAME       AUTH
--    ---------      -----
1     USER_A            1
2     USER_B            2
3     USER_C            2
4     USER_D            3
```

Meaning of Auth column:

- AUTH 1 means : SuperAdmin
- AUTH 2 means : Admin
- AUTH 3 measn : User

I can receive this data from Sql Server to DataGridView.

But I want to show on DataGridView:

- SuperAdmin instead of 1
- Admin instead of 2
- User instead of 3.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can use templates and then check for data on that and show text accordingly. check these `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860` , `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8659/Mastering-ASP-NET-DataBinding`

Comment: Maybe instead of dealing with code like this you should instead have a lookup table for the descriptions. Then you just join to your lookup table and your descriptions magically appear. You get the added benefit of no code changes if you add a new level or change the spelling.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your sql query to bring an additional description column, like

```
SELECT 
      auth, 
      CASE 
        WHEN auth = 1 THEN 
         'SuperAdmin' 
        WHEN auth = 2 THEN 
         'Admin' 
        WHEN auth = 3 THEN 
         'User' 
      /* can add an optional Else clause */
      END CASE as description
FROM yourTable
WHERE ...
```

When binding to your gridView, bind to the "description" column just created

Comment: Adding a lookup table would be a better option here imho.

Comment: @Sean Lange: does it not depend on what he wants ? This could be a view for display purposes. If these descriptions will be used somewhere else, than indeed, a lookup table might be preferrable.

Comment: Of course it is for display. But why not have a lookup table for it? If you put it in the query you have to change the query when you want to add a new value or change the spelling.

Comment: A join to a few row table is not going to kill a query. Why hard code descriptions? Avoiding a join is not a good reason to avoid data integrity. Having a lookup provides the additional benefit of ensuring your values are valid. I was merely stating that in my opinion a lookup table would be my preference.

Comment: I do not disagree with you. Mine is just the quicker solution. It may be, however, that the OP has not DB privileges - and the DBA team will object the creation of a lookup table for this case (for whatever reasons - say these values not being used anywhere else). So the solution would be to ask them to alter the query.

Comment: Yeap and that is why you have an upvote me already. Not sure why somebody else removed their vote but this crowd is pretty fickle.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new lookup table for `AUTH`:

```
AUTH  DESCRIPTION
-----------------
 1    SuperAdmin
 2    Admin
 3    User
```

Then `JOIN` to it:

```
SELECT u.*, a.DESCRIPTION 
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN AUTH a on u.AUTH = a.AUTH
```

Otherwise, use an `enum` in code to store these values along with descriptions.

```
public enum AUTH
{
    [Description("Super Admin")]
    SuperAdmin = 1,
    [Description("Admin")]
    Admin = 2,
    [Description("User")]
    User = 3
};
```

Both of these solutions would remove the magic numbers that have a meaning hidden away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataGridView`'s `CellFormatting` event if you want to do it in the GUI instead of the SQL query.
Here is an example :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == columnAuth.Index)
    {
        if (e.Value == "1")
        {
            e.Value = "SuperAdmin";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        else if (e.Value == "2")
        {
            e.Value = "Admin";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        else if (e.Value == "3")
        {
            e.Value = "User";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```